# How can I output Sql data in rows of 6 each

Tags: php, html, sql, display

My problem is that the SQL data outputted through PHP is being displayed in a vertical single column.

What I would like is for the data to be displayed In rows of 6 items then a new row should be created displaying the next 6 and so on.

Code:

```
<?php # DISPLAY COMPLETE PRODUCTS PAGE.

# Access session.
session_start() ;

# Redirect if not logged in.
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] ) ) { require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ; load() ; }

# Set page title and display header section.
$page_title = 'Shop' ;
include ( 'includes/header.html' ) ;

# Open database connection.
 require ( '..\connect_db.php' ) ;

# Retrieve items from 'shop' database table.
$q = "SELECT * FROM shop" ;
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q ) ;
if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) > 0 )
{

   # Display body section.
   echo '<UL>
        <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=1">View Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=2">View Item</a></li>          
        <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=3">View Item</a></li>
    </UL>
    ';


    #Displays every item in the store. 
  echo '<table><tr>';

$formatting = 0;
   while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
   {
      echo $formatting;
      if ($formatting = 6){
         echo '<td><strong>' . $row['item_name'] .'</strong><br><span     style="font-size:smaller">'. 
$row['item_desc'] . '</span><br><img src='. $row['item_img'].' height=200px><br>$' . $row['item_price'] . 
'<br><a href="shop_details.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">View Item</a></td></tr><tr>';
        $formatting = 0;
     }
     else 
     {
         echo $formatting;
         echo '<td><strong>' . $row['item_name'] .'</strong><br><span style="font-size:smaller">'. 
$row['item_desc'] . '</span><br><img src='. $row['item_img'].' height=200px><br>$' . $row['item_price'] . 
'<br><a href="shop_details.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">View Item</a></td>';
         $formatting = $formatting + 1;
     }
 }


 echo '</tr></table>';

    # Close database connection.
    mysqli_close( $dbc ) ; 
 }
  # Or display message.
 else { echo '<p>There are currently no items in this shop.</p>' ; }

   # Create navigation links.
   echo '<p><a href="cart.php">View Cart</a> | <a href="forum.php">Forum</a> | <a href="home.php">Home</a> | <a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a></p>' ;

     # Display footer section.
     include ( 'includes/footer.html' ) ;

    ?>
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM shop LIMIT 6

Comment: this `if ($formatting = 6)` won't do what you expect! You are assigning, not comparing. Should be `==` or `===`

Comment: Thank you for the response. It works , but only shows the first 6 items from the database, is there a way to create another row displaying the next 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, this will create a new table after every six rows. you can make changes accordingly.

```
<?php # DISPLAY COMPLETE PRODUCTS PAGE.

# Access session.
session_start() ;

# Redirect if not logged in.
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] ) ) { require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ; load() ; }

# Set page title and display header section.
$page_title = 'Shop' ;
include ( 'includes/header.html' ) ;

# Open database connection.
 require ( '..\connect_db.php' ) ;

# Retrieve items from 'shop' database table.
$q = "SELECT * FROM shop" ;
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q ) ;
if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) > 0 )
{



   # Display body section.
   echo '<UL>
        <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=1">View Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=2">View Item</a></li>          
        <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=3">View Item</a></li>
    </UL>
    ';


    #Displays every item in the store. 
  echo '<table>';

$formatting = 0;
   while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
  {
      echo $formatting;
    if ($formatting == 5){
     echo '</table><table><tr><td><strong>' . $row['item_name'] .'</strong><br><span     style="font-size:smaller">'. 
$row['item_desc'] . '</span><br><img src='. $row['item_img'].' height=200px><br>$' . $row['item_price'] . 
'<br><a href="shop_details.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">View Item</a></td></tr>';
$formatting = 0;
}
else 
    {
         echo $formatting;
        echo '<tr><td><strong>' . $row['item_name'] .'</strong><br><span style="font-size:smaller">'. 
$row['item_desc'] . '</span><br><img src='. $row['item_img'].' height=200px><br>$' . $row['item_price'] . 
'<br><a href="shop_details.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">View Item</a></td></tr>';
$formatting ++;
}
      }


   echo '</table>';

      # Close database connection.
    mysqli_close( $dbc ) ; 
  }
  # Or display message.
   else { echo '<p>There are currently no items in this shop.</p>' ; }

   # Create navigation links.
   echo '<p><a href="cart.php">View Cart</a> | <a href="forum.php">Forum</a> | <a href="home.php">Home</a> | <a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a></p>' ;

     # Display footer section.
     include ( 'includes/footer.html' ) ;

    ?>
```

Comment: I tried the code and it made the data to appear in  a column with a single item per row. Any idea how I could make it display more items in each row ?